# Error when adding Facebook SDK into Project Android

Tags: android

When I add the Facebook SDK into my project, Eclipse shows me error in the console:

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
 but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
 Versions found are:

 Path: D:\StarSoft\workspace\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
    Length: 349252
    SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
 Path: D:\StarSoft\SS_Template\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
    Length: 758727
    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
```

Please help me fix this error.

Comment: are you using eclipse? if so, look into you projects library, copy the android-support-v4.jar, and use it to replace the one located in the facebook sdk jar.

Comment: Start using android studio and gradle build will take care of dependencies .